# Find the minimum sum of elements inside a rectangle with area k in the matrix m*n

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an **m** x **n** matrix and an integer ***k***. Where ***k*** is the area of ​​the rectangle inside the matrix. Now we want to minimize the sum of the elements of this rectangle.
What is the idea of ​​this problem? Can it be solved with dynamic programming?

for example :

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

k=4

ans = 12

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake, it was corrected

Comment: In your example, shouldn't the answer be 5+6+8+9 = 28?

Comment: @Satar Your example is not clear. Could you add an explanation for it?

Comment: Also, consider adding the constraints to m, n and k. If they all are very small, like around 100, just try out all possible sub-matrices in brute force way.

Comment: Do you mean you are finding 2x2 sized rectangle in m x n matrix in that example, and so the answer is 1+2+4+5 = 12? Am I understanidng correctly?

Comment: If this problem doesn't consider rectangle's shape, there will be various shapes, like k = 4 : 1x4 / 2x2 / 4x1.